# ReactJS hooks: how to useContext in two different .js files?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have two components in the same .js file using React.createContext() and React.useContext(). Now I would like to move the Menu component in another .js file but I'm having trouble using the same context. This is the code:

```
const ManagerContext = React.createContext(null);

export default function LessonManager() {

const [title, setTitle] = React.useState('SomeOtherTitle');
const [editing, toggleEditor] = React.useState(false);

const value = React.useMemo(() => {
  return {
    title,
    setTitle,
    editing,
    toggleEditor,
    log: (t) => console.log(t)
  }
}, [title, editing]);

return (
  <ManagerContext.Provider value={value}>

    <div className='box-default expand'>

      <div className='handle' style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', width: '100%', cursor: 'grab'}}>

          <LessonMenu/>

      </div>

    </div>

  </ManagerContext.Provider>
)
}

export function LessonMenu() {

  const state = React.useContext(ManagerContext);

  return (
      <ButtonGroup size='sm'>
          <IconButton
              className='rsuite-btn menu-button'
              onClick={()=>state.toggleEditor(!state.editing)}
              icon={ <Icon icon={state.editing ? ('eye') : ('edit2')} />} />
      </ButtonGroup>
  )
}
```

I tried to export the const ManagerContext:

```
export const ManagerContext = React.createContext(null);
```

and import it in the Menu.js file I created with the Menu component, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "and import it in the Menu.js file I created with the Menu component, but it doesn't work", show us

Comment: and what does it mean doesn't work, its undefined? runtime error? please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your code seems to work, note how you need to import the context:

```
// export const ManagerContext = React.createContext(null);

import { ManagerContext } from "./Menu.js";

export function LessonMenu() {
  const { toggleEditor, editing } = React.useContext(ManagerContext);

  return (
    <ButtonGroup size="sm">
      <IconButton
        className="rsuite-btn menu-button"
        onClick={() => toggleEditor(!editing)}
        icon={<Icon icon={toggleEditor ? "eye" : "edit2"} />}
      />
    </ButtonGroup>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the import was the reason behind the error.

Comment: This will create cyclic dependency and will throw warnings

Comment: Why? Do you have a producible example for such warnings?

Comment: Yea, I'm not getting a cyclic dependency. Looks like this is what the docs suggest to do, except without showing how to do in multiple files: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: Cyclic dependencies do not happen because `useContext`, it happens because how the developer structure their files - its the developer's mistake. Methodologies like [Atomic Design](https://bradfrost.com/blog/post/atomic-web-design/) solving such issues beforehand. Feel free to browse my GitHub for examples.

Comment: @DennisVash How if the context is in App.js and another screen want to dispatch its method? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62360479/react-navigation-v5-authentication-flows-screens-as-different-files