# React Navigation v5 Authentication Flows (Screens as Different Files)

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-reducer, react-usememo

If we see in the doc example: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/ :

```
function SignInScreen() {
  const [username, setUsername] = React.useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');

  const { signIn } = React.useContext(AuthContext); // ????

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Username"
        value={username}
        onChangeText={setUsername}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Password"
        value={password}
        onChangeText={setPassword}
        secureTextEntry
      />
      <Button title="Sign in" onPress={() => signIn({ username, password })} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

`SignInScreen` is located in the same *App.js*. If we put out `SignInScreen` as a new file *SignInScreen.js*, how to dispatch the `signIn` from *SignInScreen.js*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a wrapper for `SignInScreen`

```js
// App.js
import SignInScreen from '...'

// Export the context
export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export default function App() {
  // ... some bootstrap code
  // https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/#implement-the-logic-for-restoring-the-token
  const authContext = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      signIn: async (data) => { ... },
    }),
    []
  );

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      <SignInScreen />
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

```js
import { AuthContext } from "./App.js"

function SignInScreen() {
  // Must be child of AuthContext.Provider
  const { signIn } = React.useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <View>
      ...
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I mean SignInScreen is external file and imported in App.js. SignInScreen is already child of `AuthContext.Provider`, but I'm not sure how to access the same AuthContext in SignInScreen.js?

Comment: I dont understand the problem, why is it matter if its an external file? Just import and render it

Comment: You mean how to access the same `AuthContext`? Just export it, Ill add an example

Comment: Yes, AuthContext is undefined. Tia.

Comment: @JeafGilbert See example, export the context and import it in every component which is a child of the provider

Comment: Btw additional question about this context, can we hook state in external child screen to a parent state? I want to rerender child's component if parent state changed.

Comment: I managed to update parent's state from child using that Memo, but it doesn't rerender the child's component.

Comment: If the consumer is a child of a provider so yes, better ask a new question with more details

Comment: Okay, creating new question.

Comment: Please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62387281/react-native-hook-child-state-to-parents-state-using-context