# React Native: Hook Child State to Parent's State using Context

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to rerender `{userNumbers}` in *ChildScreen*. I managed to add `userNumbers` state in *Home*, but it doesn't rerender the text.

**UserContext.js**

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

export const UserContext = createContext(null);
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { UserContext } from "../contexts/UserContext";
import ChildScreen from "ChildScreen";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function Home() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer((prevState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'ADD_USER':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          users: state.users + action.newUsers
        };
    }
  }, {
    users: 0
  });

  const userContext = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      addUsers: async data => {
        dispatch({
          type: 'ADD_USER',
          newUsers: data.newUsers
        });
      },
      userNumbers: state.users
    }),
    []
  );

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={userContext}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="ChildScreen" component={ChildScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </UserContext>
  )
}
```

**ChildScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { UserContext } from "../contexts/UserContext";

export default function ChildScreen() {
  const { addUsers, userNumbers } = React.useContext(UserContext);

  render (
    <View><Text>{userNumbers}</Text></View>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => { addUsers({newUsers: 999)}) }>
      <Text>Add 999 Users</Text>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-create the `userContext value` when `state.users` change by adding `state.users` as a dependency to useMemo otherwise you context value will keep holding the same reference of value and will note trigger change for any listeners

```
const userContext = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      addUsers: data => {
        dispatch({
          type: 'ADD_USER',
          newUsers: data.newUsers
        });
      },
      userNumbers: state.users
    }),
    [state.users] // Add a dependency here so that user update changes reference
  );
```

Also you should define your reducer to be pure, i.e it shouldn't use state from closure

```
const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer((prevState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'ADD_USER':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          users: prevState.users + action.newUsers // use prevState here
        };
    }
  }, {
    users: 0
  });
```

P.S. You need not define `addUsers` function to be `async`. `dispatch` happens asynchronously but requires a re-render to take effect and you need not wait on it

Comment: Thank you. Btw, why `state` is still in `[state, dispatch]`? Will it be used sometime?

Comment: Also ideally to make the component cleaner, you should define the reducer outside of the component.

Comment: Yes, I confused myself.

Comment: I call `addUsers()` from `<Add />` button. When I click, all the Add buttons are rerendered, which is not expected. I want to rerender only the clicked button. This happens after I added `state.users` as dependency, but I need to listen the users count. Please advice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62645730/react-native-prevent-context-dependency-rerender-all-components

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-evaluate `useContext` on `state.users` change:

```
const userContext = React.useMemo(
  () => ({
    //...
    userNumbers: state.users,
  }),
  [state.users]
);
```

Comment: Btw, my onPress button updates two values: one is local state and the other one is this user context state value. By adding this `state.users` dependency, re-rendering text of local state becomes slower. I know this is a trade off, but do you have any suggestions to make text of local state much faster?

Comment: Turns out all button components are rerendered by adding the `state.users` dependency, which is not expected. Any idea how to re-render only the clicked button?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62645730/react-native-prevent-context-dependency-rerender-all-components